# kotlin inheritance: Ambiguous field mapping detected

Tags: kotlin, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have a `MerchantAgent` document who inherits a `Partner` document. To update the `MerchantAgent` document, i created an `update` function like below

```
@Document(collection = "partner")
open class Partner {
    @Id
    open lateinit var partnerId: String
    lateinit var code: String
    open lateinit var name: String
    open lateinit var address: String
}

@Document(collection = "partner")
@TypeAlias("merchant_agent")
data class MerchantAgent(
        override var name: String,
        override var address: String,
        var globalId: String,
        var idTerminal: String
) : Partner() {
    fun update(form: MerchantAgent): MerchantAgent {
        return this.copy(
                name = form.name,
                address = form.address,
                globalId = form.globalId,
                idTerminal = form.idTerminal
    }
}
```

when i start my application i have the below error

> Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException:
> Ambiguous field mapping detected! Both public java.lang.String
> Partner.name and private java.lang.String MerchantAgent.name
> map to the same field name name! Disambiguate using @Field annotation!

Comment: Why do you override name and address properties ? It is not clear why it is required.